# number of representations by sums of three squares (with coefficients)

Tags: nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, quadratic-forms

There are formulas for counting the number of representations of a positive integer $N$ as a sum of three integer squares. What is a reference for
$$
\#\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbf{N}^3: 5^4 x^2+y^2+z^2=N\}
?$$

Comment: Is there a reason you are interested in this specific quadratic form?

Comment: yes there is one

Comment: and what is it?

Comment: i want to use it

Comment: The paper Mingyu Kim, Diagonal odd-regular ternary quadratic forms, Journal of Number Theory, Volume 224, 2021, Pages 67-94, https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jnt.2021.01.014 doesn't exactly address the question, but may give ideas. 
Abstract: A (positive definite primitive integral) quadratic form is called odd-regular if it represents every odd positive integer which is locally represented. In this paper, we show that there are at most 147 diagonal odd-regular ternary quadratic forms and prove the odd-regularities of all but six candidates.

Comment: Another source that may give some ideas is https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1972120/ternary-quadratic-forms

Comment: International Journal of Number Theory Vol. 17, No. 03, pp. 547-575 (2021) Local densities of diagonal integral ternary quadratic forms at odd primes by Edna Jones, https://doi.org/10.1142/S1793042120400357 seems more helpful. The abstract says the paper contains formulas which "can be used to compute the representation numbers of certain ternary quadratic forms." See also https://services.math.duke.edu/~elj31/talks/LocalDensitiesTernaryQuadFormsOddPrimes_20200228.pdf

Comment: Golubeva, E.P. Representation of numbers, divisible by a large square, by positive ternary quadratic forms. J Math Sci 43, 2519–2530 (1988), https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01374981 looks relevant.

Comment: have you had a look at any of the references I gave? or the one in the answer from user @piepie?

Comment: Hello, this is amazing, thanks! Edna Jones' paper is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Perhaps you could post a summary of that paper as an answer to your question.

Comment: happy to do that when i find time

Comment: Good. You asked us to find time to answer your question; I hope you can find time to write up and post a summary.

Answer (score -1):

You may refer to Theorem 13 of the paper 'On the Number of Representations of Integers by various Quadratic and Higher Forms' by Nikos Bagis and M.L Glasser. ([paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.0466.pdf))